# Python: calling upper() on words containing non-latin characters

Tags: python, python-2.x, uppercase

I have a file with words in lines, ex

```
А
б
Вв
Гг
```

(non-latin letters)
etc.

I want to get this:

```
А
Б
ВВ
ГГ
```

while after the code runs I see no changes

here is code:

```
f = open('sample.csv')
for line in f:
    for sampleword in line.split():
        print sampleword.upper()
```

Non-latin characters are not capitilized. What's the problem?

Comment: What are the input, output, and expected output?

Comment: It works for me. It prints A AB ABC. Is that not what you want?

Comment: Yes, that's right. Maybe the problem is that I work with non-english letters?

Comment: `words = ['ab', 'cd', 'ef']` and `for w in words: print w.upper()` works ok, cannot reproduce. Could you verify what exactly are you reading from file?

Comment: So, the _real_ question is: How to uppercase non-english/latin letters? Could you edit your question accordingly? And please add an example!

Comment: Please add your input, your output, and the desired output. Right now, we can only guess what your problem is. On a side note, if you are using non-latin (i.e. "non-english") characters, then I highly recommend python 3. Python 2 does not handle unicode well.

Comment: Maybe you should use the `codecs` module and read it encoding `utf-8`

Comment: In Python 3, it seems to work fine: `"λ".upper()` yields `'Λ'`. Not so in Python 2.

Answer (score 2):

Solution for capitalizing non-latin letters in Python 2 is to use unicode strings:

```
words = [u'łuk', u'ćma']
assert [w.upper() for w in words] == [u'ŁUK', u'ĆMA']
```

To read unicode from file you may refer to [official Python manual](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/unicode.html#reading-and-writing-unicode-data):

> Reading Unicode from a file is therefore simple:

```
import codecs
f = codecs.open('unicode.rst', encoding='utf-8')
for line in f:
    print repr(line)
```

Comment: But what about files?

Comment: Ok, that's great, but now I get smth like u'\u0410\u041a\u0418\u0411\u0410\u041d\u041a' in my output file

Comment: Are you doing `print repr(word.upper())`? `repr()` is used just to show that string is a `unicode`, and not `str`. You may simply print line itself - `print word.upper()`.

Comment: otherwise I get an err message UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xd0 in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)

Comment: @PeterKungurtsev: what is your input file encoding? Maybe it wasn't UTF-8 in first place?

Comment: sample.csv: text/plain; charset=utf-8